# HTML not formatting correctly in a for-each test

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am sure that my logic is not correct.  However I am not sure how to resolve this without multiple for-each tests.

Perhaps a for-each is not the correct way to go?  I would appreciate any advice.  Additinally I am using XSLT 1.0 in case that is necessary information.

Here is the XML that I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FIGURES>
    <FIGURE>
        <TITLE>Title 1</TITLE>
        <DESC>Description 1</DESC>
        <CONTENT>Content 1</CONTENT>
    </FIGURE>
    <FIGURE>
        <TITLE>Title 2</TITLE>
        <DESC>Description 2</DESC>
        <CONTENT>Content 2</CONTENT>
    </FIGURE>
    <FIGURE>
        <TITLE>Title 2</TITLE>
        <DESC>Description 2</DESC>
        <CONTENT>Content 2</CONTENT>
    </FIGURE>
</FIGURES>
```

Here is the XSLT that I am trying:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list">

      <xsl:for-each select="//FIGURE">

        <li>
          <a href="#section-{position()}"><h3><xsl:value-of select="TITLE" /></h3></a>
          <p><xsl:value-of select="DESC" /></p>
        </li>

        <div class="content">
          <div id="section-{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="CONTENT" />
          </div>
        </div>                           

      </xsl:for-each>  

    </ul>    
  </div>

</xsl:template>
```

Here is the HTML that I want but am not getting:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <a href="#section-1"><h3>Title 1</h3></a>
      <p>Description 1</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#section-2"><h3>Title 2</h3></a>
      <p>Description 2</p>
    </li>   
    <li>
      <a href="#section-3"><h3>Title 3</h3></a>
      <p>Description 3</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <div id="section-1">
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section-1">
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>  
    <div id="section-1">
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>          
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the HTML that I get, but do not want:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>
      <a href="#section-1"><h3>Title 1</h3></a>
      <p>Description 1</p>
    </li>
   <div class="content">
     <div id="section-1">Content 1</div>
   </div>
   <li>
     <a href="#section-2"><h3>Title 2</h3></a>
     <p>Description 2</p>
   </li>
   <div class="content">
     <div id="section-2">Content 2</div>
   </div>
   <li>
     <a href="#section-3"><h3>Title 2</h3></a>
     <p>Description 2</p>
   </li>
   <div class="content">
     <div id="section-3">Content 2</div>
   </div>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**EDIT** Using Sean's example I figured it out.  I was just missing the select attribute on the  tags.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <div class="container">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURES">
  <ul class="list">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="FIGURE" mode="titles" />
  </ul>  
  <div class="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="FIGURE" mode="content" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="titles">
  <li>
    <a href="#section-{position()}">
      <h3><xsl:value-of select="TITLE" /></h3>
    </a>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="DESC" /></p>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="content">
  <div id="section-{position()}">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="CONTENT" /></p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What are you getting instead? NB your internal href needs to refer to a named anchor element, not to the id of a div element.

Comment: @EJP: Editted.  The last section of html shows what I am getting but do is not formatted properly.

Comment: "Perhaps a for-each is not the correct way to go?" - `xsl:for-each` is _almost_ always not the correct way to go.

Comment: @Daniel Haley: That's what I'm still learning.  This site suggests using xsl:for-each when context position matters, and I'm using position.  http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 stylesheet...***

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
   <body>
     <div class="container">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURES">
  <ul class="list">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="titles" />
  </ul>  
  <div class="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="content" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="titles">
  <li>
    <a href="#section-{position()}">
      <h3><xsl:value-of select="TITLE" /></h3>
    </a>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="DESC" /></p>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="content">
  <div id="section-{position()}">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="CONTENT" /></p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...when applied to the referenced input document, will yield...**

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#section-1"><h3>Title 1</h3></a><p>Description 1</p>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section-2"><h3>Title 2</h3></a><p>Description 2</p>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#section-3"><h3>Title 2</h3></a><p>Description 2</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="content">
        <div id="section-1">
          <p>Content 1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section-2">
          <p>Content 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section-3">
          <p>Content 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### Update

If you are not using xsl:strip-space (you should, as I gave this to you in the solution), or if for some reason, you have other nodes interspersed between the FIGURE elements, then this style-sheet will give you a more robust solution...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <html>
   <body>
     <div class="container">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURES">
  <ul class="list">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="titles" />
  </ul>  
  <div class="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="content" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="titles">
  <li>
    <a href="#section-{count(preceding-sibling::FIGURE)+1}">
      <h3><xsl:value-of select="TITLE" /></h3>
    </a>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="DESC" /></p>
  </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURE" mode="content">
  <div id="section-{count(preceding-sibling::FIGURE)+1}">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="CONTENT" /></p>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but when I try this I do not see the href attribute and the id attribute incrementing as I expected.  The id on the div's for instand is section-2, section-4, and section-6 instead of section-1, section-2, and secton-3.

Comment: @Mdd That's likely because: either you are not using my solution exactly, or there is something that you have neglected to mention about the actual input document you are using. Please find an updated solution that robustly handles input documents with other nodes interspered between the FIGURE elements.

Comment: I see now.  I missed the xsl:strip-space when I tried the original solution you posted.  Thanks Sean!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would be the most efficient way but should solve the purpose:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="./FIGURES"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURES">
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//FIGURE"/>
   </ul>
  <div class="content">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//CONTENT"/>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CONTENT">
<div id="section-{position()}">
<p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p>
</div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FIGURE">
<li>
<a href="#section-{position()}">
<h3><xsl:value-of select="./TITLE"/></h3>
</a>
<p><xsl:value-of select="./DESC"/></p>
</li>
</xsl:template>
```